# add data to NSMUtableArrray with keys by for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm new in iPhone, I want to add elements to NSMutableArray with each element's name 
I created a MutableArray for keys , then other array for elements that I get them from object called Pages.

I wrote the following code

```
NSMutableArray *myArray;


NSMutableArray *arrayKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"b_pag_id", @"b_pag_bo_id", @"b_pag_num", @"b_pag_note", @"b_page_mark", @"b_page_stop", @"b_pag_user_id", nil];

    for (int x=0; x<[pages count]; x++) {
        Pages *myPages = (Pages *)[self.pages objectAtIndex:x];

        NSString *b_pag_id2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myPages.b_pag_id];
        NSString *b_pag_bo_id2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myPages.b_pag_bo_id];
        NSString *b_pag_num2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myPages.b_pag_num];
        NSString *b_pag_note2 = myPages.b_pag_note;
        NSString *b_page_mark2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myPages.b_page_mark];
        NSString *b_page_stop2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myPages.b_page_stop];
        NSString *b_pag_user_id2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myPages.b_pag_user_id];

        NSMutableArray *arrayValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:b_pag_id2, b_pag_bo_id2, b_pag_num2, b_pag_note2, b_page_mark2, b_page_stop2, b_pag_user_id2, nil];

        NSDictionary *theReqDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayValue forKeys:arrayKey];

        myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:theReqDictionary,nil];
    }

   NSLog(@"array size: %d", [myArray count]);
```

I want to add every element to its key for example 
element (b_pag_id2) its key (b_pag_id) ..etc
is this right ?? or how to do this ??
consider that   NSLog(@"array size: %d", [myArray count]); gives me 1 and the size of my elements is 14

Comment: Why don't you just create a single dictionary instead of going through all this trouble.

Comment: can you show me the code please because I'm new in iPhone

Comment: why the code wont help me ??? I understand the idea when I read the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the loop you need to initialize the aray

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Inside the loop replace following:

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:theReqDictionary,nil];
```

with

```
[myArray addObject:theReqDictionary];
```

The problem is that you are creating a new array with 1 dictionary in every loop iteration. Instead you need to initialize the array and add values one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Each time through your loop you are creating a new array for `myArray` that has only one element.  You should initialize an empty NSMutableArray before the loop and then simply add your new object to it instead of using `arrayWithObjects:` to create `myArray`..

Comment: but can you tell me how to add elements properly ??

Comment: Look at the documentation for `NSMutableArray`; it describes methods for adding elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here i'm giving a short example, and i hope this will help you.
see this code :-

```
NSMutableArray *arrayValue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Value1",@"Value2",@"Value3", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrayKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    [dic setObject:[arrayValue objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[arrayKey objectAtIndex:i]];
}

//and you can see this by printing it using nslog-

NSLog(@"%@",[dic valueForKey:@"1"]);
```

Thank you!!!